# rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ReadOnlyException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to deploy an app to EC2 following [this](http://dennissuratna.com/rails-deployment-aws2/) tutorial. When I run rake db:migrate, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                         
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL)
```

when running **ls -l**

```
total 16                                                                                                                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Apr 16 03:55 development.sqlite3                                                                                                                
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 16 03:48 migrate                                                                                                                            
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5989 Apr 16 03:48 schema.rb                                                                                                                          
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  345 Apr 16 03:48 seeds.rb                                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Apr 16 12:28 test.sqlite3
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the sqlite file? There should be a `my_db.sqlite3` in the `APP_ROOT/db` directory. To see the permissions, use `ls -l` when you're in the `db` directory

Comment: I updated the post. What should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running in development mode on the server (generally not what you want to do, but can be useful for learning), you need to modify the permissions of your sqlite database. So, if you're running an ubuntu AMI on EC2 (which I think you are) run `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu development.sqlite3` and `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu test.sqlite3`.

This changes the user who owns the file (chown = change owner) to the ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little adjust to the Peter response, making user dynamically, and changing permissions of other files inside the same project recursively:

```
sudo chown -R $USER .
```